# Warning: include(1) [function.include]: failed to open stream

Tags: wordpress

I have this massage at the top of the wordpress site and can`t enter in admin area!

> Warning: include(1) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/pharmme/public_html/bphsa.bg/wp-config.php
>   on line 21
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '1' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php52/pear') in
>   /home/pharmme/public_html/bphsa.bg/wp-config.php on line 21

What is the problem?

```
?php
/**
 * The*/include /* base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * 
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'pharmme_wp573'); <--- line 21
```

Comment: Please add what is on `wp-config.php` line 21 and the parts above. Be sure to replace passwords if they are included. Also did you change the `wp-config.php` or did you let WordPress generate it by itself?

Comment: // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'pharmme_wp573'); <--- line 21

Comment: We need a bigger part. Add it to your question as an edit.

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is the problem.

`* The*/include /* base configuration for WordPress`

should be:

`* The include base configuration for WordPress`

Now PHP thinks it the [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function. Which is causing the error.